# Wildfly и YouTrack не запускаются вместе

Tags: сервер, развертывание, jboss, wildfly, youtrack

Решил поставить YouTrack на сервер, где также запущен сервер приложений Wildfly. YT останавливает Wildfly и сам стартует со сбоями. Порты не пересекаются. Как их подружить?

Comment: Что значит останавливает и что значит сбои? Для нас это абсолютно неинформативные сообщения.

Comment: Wildfly останавливается с сообщением process was killed. И YT зацикливается на hub starting

Comment: юзай докер и не парься

Comment: докер тоже не устанавливается,  что-то не так с билдом дебиана

Comment: что значит не устанавливается? какие ошибки? Вроде никогда проблем не возникало (сижу под арчем, или на впске под убунтой)

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lxc-docker*
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lxc-docker*'`

Comment: шаг 3 https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/debian/#/update-your-apt-repository

Comment: у меня wheezy, предварительную подготовку описанную в статье сделал

Comment: документация докера предписывает вам удалить lxc-docker, если его вообще не существует как пакета, то цель уже достигнута сама собой

Comment: `root@s1:~# sudo docker run hello-world
docker: An error occurred trying to connect: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/create: read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer.
See 'docker run --help'.`

Comment: При старте Hello World

Comment: `Your Linux kernel version 2.6.32-042stab108.8 is not supported for running docker. Please upgrade your kernel to 3.10.0 or newer.`